# Laravel10+vue3+inertia+ts において Userの型拡張をする方法は？

Tags: laravel, typescript, vue.js

あるページで、User情報から表示の分岐をさせています。
そのため、LaravelのUser Table で追加した role を参照します。

これをvue内に書いているのですが、ワーニングを消すことができない状態です。
IDEは VSCODE を使用しています。

```
const user = usePage().props.auth.user;
const numberOfApiKeys = user.role === "admin" ? 5 : 1;
```

上記のようにすると role の部分において、下記メッセージが表示されます
`プロパティ 'role' は型 'User' に存在しません。ts(2339)`

そこで、型を定義するためにinterfaceを追加しました。

```
interface User {
  role: string;
}

const user = usePage().props.auth.user as User;
```

すると `usePage().props.auth.user as User` の部分において
`型 'import("/home/my_project/vendor/laravel/breeze/stubs/inertia-vue-ts/resources/js/types/index").User' から型 'User' への変換は、互いに十分に重複できないため間違っている可能性があります。意図的にそうする場合は、まず式を 'unknown' に変換してください。`

というメッセージになります。
確かに vendor 下の types/index で下記の通りUserが型定義されています。

```
export interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    email_verified_at: string;
}

export type PageProps<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>> = T & {
    auth: {
        user: User;
    };
};
```

vendorフォルダ下のファイルは操作しないほうが良いと考えています。
その場合、後から追加したデータ項目をvue内で使用したいとき、
TSの警告を消すためにはどのように対応すればよいでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。